# Video Embed Field: Pull in Original Title & Description

Tags: files, nodes

I'm using the [video embed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) in Drupal 7. I'd like to pull in the original title/description from youtube/vimeo, and then have an (optional) additional user description field. How do I get it to use the original title/description directly from youtube/vimeo?